# Purpose of $scope.this property?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

**UPDATE**: [angular 1.3.0-rc4](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#130-rc4-unicorn-hydrafication-2014-10-01) removed $scope.this see [commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5572b40b15ed06969c8e0e92866c5afd088484b4)

Each instance of a **$scope** has a property named **this** that points back to itself.
Currently (*1.2.0rc1*) it's not prefixed with **$**(*public/protected*) or **$$**(*internal*) so it doesn't hint  that it's an angular specific property.

What is the use case for it?

Comment: I've seen `this` on scopes in the console, but never thought much about it. There's even [a test](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/44ad61e56c04f445d059048838d8de3adbc63090/test/ng/rootScopeSpec.js#L46-50) to ensure it exists. That said, I can't find any uses of it in the codebase. Very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

This question had me grepping all through the codebase for an explanation; I finally got a hint from [an old test](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/8f0dcbab804180828d6859b1340c86cf161209fb#L38L46).

Since AngularJS expressions are evaluated in the context of a scope, the scope needs to have a property called `this` that refers to itself so that *expressions* that contain `this` work. Take the following example:

```html
<div ng-controller="FirstController">
  `this.num` (with normal scope): {{this.num}}
</div>

<div ng-controller="SecondController">
  `this.num` (with scope.this removed): {{this.num}}
</div>
```

```javascript
app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('FirstController', function($scope) {
  $scope.num = 10;
});

app.controller('SecondController', function($scope) {
  delete $scope['this'];
  $scope.num = 10;
});
```

The second example does not work; see http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/mzbpz/ for a demonstration.

Comment: I thought of that myself but I've never seen any example that uses {{this.prop}} anywhere in any official examples and I don't see where it could be useful.

Comment: Yeah, other than that spec, I've never seen it used either. I suppose it could be useful if you call `$eval` and pass in a function, maybe even using an external library that uses `this`. On a more fundamental level, I guess it makes sense to support `this` on a scope evaluation because *regular* JavaScript execution contexts always have `this` available.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll leave this still open for a while, maybe we'll get lucky and someone with inside(angular team) knowledge will see this.